# ¿Plantillas laterales es sinonimo de backticks?

Tags: javascript

Ya lo busque por google pero no encuentro respuestas utiles;(

Muchas gracias

Comment: Son plantillas de cadena, _template strings_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás buscando [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (o *template literals*), que son las cadenas rodeadas por *backticks* que permiten expresiones embebidas o *sustituciones*.

El carácter se llama *backtick* (acento grave, comilla invertida).

Así, algo que normalmente se haría con

```js
let a = 5;
let b = 10;
console.log('Quince es ' + (a + b) + ' y\nno ' + (2 * a + b) + '.');
// "Quince es 15 y
// no 20."
```

Pasa a hacerse con

```js
let a = 5;
let b = 10;
console.log(`Quince es ${a + b} y
no ${2 * a + b}.`);
// "Quince es 15 y
// no 20."
```

Otro ejemplo divertido es pasar de

```js
let tabla = 5;
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) console.log(tabla + "x" + i + " = " + tabla * i + "\n");
```

a usar

```js
let tabla = 5;
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) console.log(`${tabla}x${i} = ${tabla * i}
`);
```

Comment: Buena respuesta; no me gustaron los `var` de los últimos ejemplos. De todos modos, +1

Comment: @Triby Tengo 84 años y a veces se me olvida lo de la modernidá. Gracias!